# Need to populate one table with data from another table in same database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to populate one table from another table with mysql. First table is users and the second table is technicians .

Users contains : userID, surname, firstname, loginid, password, accesslevel .

Technicians contains : techID, tech_surname, tech_firstname, tech_loginid, tech_password, tech_accesslevel.

When I add a user, I want the technicians table to populate if accesslevel=tech and users.loginid is not equal to technicians.tech_loginid.

I have tried several things and the result is that either no record is added or all records in users where accesslevel=tech are added each time, giving me several duplicate records.

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO technicians (techID, tech_surname, tech_firstname, tech_loginid, tech_passwrd, tech_accesslevel)
SELECT firstname, surname, loginid, accesslevel, passwrd, tech_loginid
FROM users, technicians
WHERE accesslevel='tech' AND 'loginid!=tech_loginid'
```

It doesn't work and if I remove the AND statement from the WHERE clause it pushes all the records each time a new user is added with accesslevel=tech.

What am I doing wrong? I've searched for hours for an answer.

Cheers

Comment: your select statement has different types of columns than your insert statement. Also its unclear how do you generate techID , simply copy a userId or its a unique id, and they are only share loginid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're trying to insert those technicians that already do not exist in that table so a query would be something like this

```
INSERT INTO technicians  (techID, tech_surname, tech_firstname, tech_loginid, tech_passwrd, tech_accesslevel) 
SELECT loginid, surname, firstname, tech_loginid, passwrd, accesslevel 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN technicians ON loginid = tech_loginid
WHERE accesslevel='tech' and tech_loginid IS null
```

Comment: Hasan, thanks for that. I added an AND in the WHERE accesslevel=tech and it worked wonderfully. Thanks. Could I use the same to delete records when they are removed from the users table. Would it be DELETE FROM technicians etc.? Cheers mate!

Comment: @Spud If it worked for you then you might want to upvote and accept the answer. For delete a different but similar query can be used. You might want to post a new question for that or experiment with it.

Comment: interesting, you post similar answer with errors, then edit it to be the same as mine. nice. anyway I prefer not exists to outer join.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub the actual answer is that he needs to use outer join; the error in my post was regarding missing where clause and incorrect order of columns in select but that is irrelevant. And your answer and my answer are very different.

Comment: hmm so your saying mine will not suit the needs? I dont have a db in place and could you elaborate whats wrong with my approach, I think im always taking it and it works usually.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub I never said your answer is wrong my friend. I'm saying crux of my answer is about outer join. I'm not sure what are we debating here.

Comment: ah I see. I came to that conclusion because you said he "needs" to use outer join, while if my answer is correct too it can be said that he "can" use outer join. nevermind , nothing to discuss, ill +1 you anyway since you call me friend ;)

Comment: @Hasan - I think I upvoted you correctly, not sure, it's the first one I've done. If you have a minute could you take a look at another question I've posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491126/need-to-insert-from-two-tables-into-a-single-table), I'm stumped by it. By the way, I was able to figure out how to edit and delete the technicians table through the users table. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
    INSERT INTO technicians 
(techID, tech_surname, tech_firstname, tech_loginid, tech_passwrd, tech_accesslevel) 
    SELECT 
GetTechId(),surname, firstname, loginid , passwrd, accesslevel  FROM users u
    WHERE
NOT EXISTS (select 1 from technicians t where t.loginid=u.loginid) and 
u.accesslevel='tech'.
```