# difficulty populating data from another table

Tags: mysql

As the title above, I would like to insert values from a table to another

I followed the suggested answer here, 
[Need to populate one table with data from another table in same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396938/need-to-populate-one-table-with-data-from-another-table-in-same-database)

mysql code turned up to

```
INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `PlayerWL`) SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`, `betdb`.`PlayerID`,`betdb`.`BetAmount` FROM `betdb` LEFT OUTER JOIN `profitdb` ON `betdb`.`BetID` = `profitdb`.`BetID`
```

but I'm encountering this error

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`, `betdb`.`PlayerID`,`betdb`.`BetAmount` FROM `betdb` 
LE' at line 3
```

what could be my fault here?

Comment: your query is wrong you dont need the part `VALUES (....)`

Comment: either use `VALUES` or `SELECT` for `INSERT`, not both, and besides that, you are using ``betdb`` in both your `FROM` and your `JOIN` with no alias, introduce an alias for at least one of them

Comment: if you do a select into an insert you dont need VALUES

Comment: also why this left outer join on the same table ? it does not make any sense.

Comment: sorry I'm just a beginner here, I just followed the idea of the link I used as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do `INSERT INTO TABLE A(field1,2,3) VALUES(1,2,3)` and then perform a SELECT so the error means you should do `INSERT ... VALUES .... **;** SELECT`   to perform 2 queries  but what you really want is:

```
INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `Outcome`) 
SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`, `betdb`.`PlayerID`,`betdb`.`BetAmount` FROM `betdb`
```

to copy data from one table to another, read: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Comment: another question, I have new columns that will come from other table, how would I write the query? let's say to get 'AgentRisk', you need to get it from "Agents" table same goes for 'SubAgentRisk', so the query like INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `Outcome`,'AgentRisk','SubAgentRisk') 
SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`, `betdb`.`PlayerID`,`betdb`.`BetAmount` FROM `betdb` SELECT `Risk` FROM 'agentdb' SELECT `Risk` FROM `subagentdb`